# Get records from mysql table using nested select

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql table named **request**:

```
requestID
requeststatusID
requestClientFirstName
requestClientLastName
requestClientNumber
requestClientEmail
```

I want to get all the records where the requeststatusID is NOT 4, 5 or 6 and to get requestClientFirstName that starts with letter A OR requestClientLastName that starts with letter A or requestClientEmail that starts with letter A

One more thing...if user enter 2 for example instead of letter A, I want to get all requestClientNumber that starts with 2...

I am trying with following code :

```
(SELECT *
FROM (`request`)
WHERE requeststatusID NOT IN (`4`, `5`, `6`))
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * 
FROM (`request`) 
WHERE requestClientLastName LIKE (`A%`));
```

but the code miserable fails...Anyone can help?

Comment: Why do you want use LEFT JOIN instead of WHERE?

Comment: I get same error even If I use where....

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `request`
WHERE requeststatusID NOT IN ('4', '5', '6')
AND CASE
    WHEN ('2' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$')  THEN
requestClientNumber LIKE '2%'
ELSE
( requestClientFirstName LIKE 'A%' OR  requestClientLastName LIKE 'A%' OR  requestClientEmail LIKE 'A%'  )
END
```